# how to create pdf/X-3 document using Quartz

Tags: quartz-graphics

Some printer require pdf/x-3 format pdf to work. Before snow leopard, there's an option to use the ColorSync Utilities to get around this problem and create nice 300 dpi pdf/x-3 documents. With snow leopard, this is no longer possible because it would only create 72 dpi pdf/x-3 documents.

Is there some library available that could convert a pdf document created from Quartz into 300 dpi pdf/x-3 format?